# How to get url id in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page that has an id (this id comes from a table in Mysql) in its url. Now I need to get that id from the url in a variable and store it into another Mysql table. Using $_GET method it should work, but in my case it isn't, I am using $_GET inside a IF condition, can it be an issue?  Below is the link of the url...What could be the issue here?

......../full_post.php?**post_id=19**

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['reply'])){
        $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
```

Comment: Could you try printing the entire array (i.e. `print_r($_GET);`) and see if that prints anything?

Comment: Why should it be an issue? What behavior would you expect if the statement isn't executed or when it is executed? Have you tried it or is it just hypothetical?

Comment: Whenever using $_GET or $_POST variables, you have to check first if the variable exists. Especially $_GET variables can easily be manipulated by the client

Comment: Yes, @DarshanMehta  I did this and got .....       Array ( [post_id] => 19 ) .... which means post_id is properly taken into the variable...... i can't send and store it into mysql table...... i am using this command......             $insert_query = "INSERT INTO replies
       (post_id,user_id,reply,files,time) 
       values ('$post_id','$user_id','$reply','$upload_file','$current_date')";

Comment: @TariqulIslam it might look silly but can you try printing `$_GET["post_id"]` (i.e. replace single quotes with double quotes)?

Comment: @DarshanMehta.... it prints 19 both with single quote and double quote...

Comment: I got the point of mistake...... i was submitting the form before getting the $post_id=$_GET['post_id']..... i just moved this line from inside of IF condition and pasted it before the form....and i got the post_id value in my Mysql table...Thanks all for helping...

Comment: Is it a post request? This snippet works only for a post request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your if condition when you have a button like this one:

```
  <form action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="reply" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Yes, I have both form and button.... I made some small changes now it stores the variable name into the table like $post_id NOT the value 19...... any idea?